# How to use geopy vicenty distance over dataframe columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopy

I have a dataframe with location column which contains lat,long location as follows

```
 deviceid                             location        
1102ADb75        [12.9404578177, 77.5548244743]
```

How to get the distance between consecutive rows using geopy's vicenty function? 
I tried following code

```
from geopy.distance import vincenty 
vincenty(df['location'].shift(-1), df['location']).miles
```

It returns following error -
***TypeError: __new__() takes at most 4 arguments (5 given)***

EDIT - where df is a Pandas dataframe containing deviceId & Location columns as shown above 
Also

```
print type(df)
class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'
```

Comment: what exactly is `df` in your case? please add what it is to the question description as `dataframe` is a bit vague, e.g. print(df, type(df)) would be nice

Comment: Edited, anyway 1st line says I have a dataframe

Comment: ok, I was not aware that it is a Pandas dataframe; it is better to be clear and specific when asking a question

Answer (score 3):

Based on [geopy's github](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/blob/ba50914042dea4ee1ce45deb9ef226751faefc3b/geopy/distance.py#L301-304) you should pass two tuples to the `vincenty` function:

```
    >>> from geopy.distance import vincenty
    >>> point_a = (41.49008, -71.312796)
    >>> point_b = (41.499498, -81.695391)
    >>> print(vincenty(point_a, point_b).miles)
    538.3904451566326
```

**EDIT**:

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.distance import vincenty

data = [[101, [41.49008, -71.312796]],
        [202, [41.499498, -81.695391]]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['deviceid', 'location'])

print df
>>>    deviceid                 location
>>> 0       101   [41.49008, -71.312796]
>>> 1       202  [41.499498, -81.695391]

print vincenty(df['location'][0], df['location'][1]).miles
>>> 538.390445157
```

Comment: I know that's why the question, not able to figure our how to do it